# CSS nth-child not returning quite what was expected

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-selectors

I am trying to create a table dynamically. And update the cell values accordingly. The values are returned asynchronously, therefore they can theoretically refer to any column. The number of columns can be different at any time depending on the situation but the number of rows for this section of the table is constant (7).

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.dummyTable td.components:nth-child(5n+2) {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<table class="dummyTable" style="display: table;">

<tbody>
<tr>

<th style="background-color:#898b8c; color:white">A</th>
<th style="background-color:#898b8c; color:white">B</th>
<th style="background-color:#898b8c; color:white">C</th>
<th style="background-color: rgb(137, 139, 140); padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px; cursor: pointer;">37</th>
<th style="background-color: rgb(137, 139, 140); padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px; cursor: pointer;">38</th>
<th style="background-color: rgb(137, 139, 140); padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px; cursor: pointer;">36</th>
<th style="background-color: rgb(137, 139, 140); padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px; cursor: pointer;">39</th>
<th style="background-color: rgb(137, 139, 140); padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px; cursor: pointer;">40</th>
</tr>

<tr>
      <td rowspan="3">A</td>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>C</td>

      <td style="background-color: #4fefa4 ">0</td>
      <td style="background-color: #fff082 ">1</td>
      <td style="background-color: #4fefa4 ">0</td>
      <td style="background-color: #4fefa4 ">0</td>
      <td style="background-color: #4fefa4 ">0</td>
</tr>

<tr>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>C</td>
      <td style="background-color: #4fefa4 ">0</td>
      <td style="background-color: #4fefa4 ">0</td>
      <td style="background-color: #4fefa4 ">0</td>
      <td style="background-color: #4fefa4 ">0</td>
      <td style="background-color: #4fefa4 ">0</td>
</tr>
<tr>
      <td></td>
      <td style="background-color:#d5e7ed;">Total</td>
      <td id="37" style="background-color:#d5e7ed">0</td>
      <td id="38" style="background-color:#d5e7ed">1</td>
      <td id="36" style="background-color:#d5e7ed">0</td>
      <td id="39" style="background-color:#d5e7ed">0</td>
      <td id="40" style="background-color:#d5e7ed">0</td>
</tr>

<tr>
      <td rowspan="7">S</td>
      <td rowspan="7">E</td>

      <td>s1</td>
      <td class="components" style="background-color:#4fefa4">0</td>
      <td class="components" style="background-color:#4fefa4">0</td>
      <td class="components" style="background-color:#fff082">2</td>
      <td class="components" style="background-color:#4fefa4">0</td>
      <td class="components" style="background-color:#4fefa4">0</td>
</tr>
<tr>
      <td>s2</td>
      <td class="components" style="background-color:#fff082">1</td>
      <td class="components" style="background-color:#4fefa4">0</td>
      <td class="components" style="background-color:#4fefa4">0</td>
      <td class="components" style="background-color:#4fefa4">0</td>
      <td class="components" style="background-color:#4fefa4">0</td>
</tr>
<tr>
      <td>s3</td>
      <td class="components" style="background-color:#4fefa4">0</td>
      <td class="components" style="background-color:#4fefa4">0</td>
      <td class="components" style="background-color:#fff082">3</td>
      <td class="components" style="background-color:#fff082">3</td>
      <td class="components" style="background-color:#fff082">4</td>
</tr>
    <tr>
      <td>s4</td>
      <td class="components" style="background-color:#4fefa4">0</td>
      <td class="components" style="background-color:#4fefa4">0</td>
      <td class="components" style="background-color:#fff082">1</td>
      <td class="components" style="background-color:#4fefa4">0</td>
      <td class="components" style="background-color:#4fefa4">0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>s5</td>
      <td class="components" style="background-color:#4fefa4">0</td>
      <td class="components" style="background-color:#4fefa4">0</td>
      <td class="components" style="background-color:#fff082">1</td>
      <td class="components" style="background-color:#4fefa4">0</td>
      <td class="components" style="background-color:#4fefa4">0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>s6</td>

      <td class="components" style="background-color:#4fefa4">0</td>
      <td class="components" style="background-color:#4fefa4">0</td>
      <td class="components" style="background-color:#4fefa4">0</td>
      <td class="components" style="background-color:#4fefa4">0</td>
      <td class="components" style="background-color:#4fefa4">0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>s7</td>
      <td class="components" style="background-color:#fff082">1</td>
      <td class="components" style="background-color:#4fefa4">0</td>
      <td class="components" style="background-color:#4fefa4">0</td>
      <td class="components" style="background-color:#4fefa4">0</td>
      <td class="components" style="background-color:#4fefa4">0</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I am trying to update a column at a time with nth child. My thinking was that all I need to know is how many columns there are in the table and which column I am dealing with at the time.

For example if there were 5 columns, n would be 5 I think then the constant would modify which column I'm talking about.

i.e. 5n+1 should update column 1 of a 5 columned table. And 3n+2 should modify column 2 of a 3 columned table.

The columns I'm referring to are the ones with a class "components".

The problems I think I am running into is I'm not sure how the "components" cells are indexed. i.e. Whether they go row by row or column by column.

I am thinking kind of in terms of nth term formulas in maths:

So if a formula was 5n+0 in this case:

I am imagining the first highlighted cell would be 5: 5(1) + 0 = 5
Then the next highlighted cell index would be 10: 5(2) + 0 = 10

I am also unsure if they start at a zero index or 1.

This process is working for me for every row but the first one. But when I'm testing in the snippet it doesn't seem to move exactly how I would've expected.

(Note) I have modified the example to take a section of the original returned table and the code is in CSS rather than jQuery and instead of modifying the value I am changing the colour here. This was for simplicity because I don't think this will affect the logic.

Comment: Nope. `n` is a variable. `2n`, for example, refers to every even-numbered child. It has nothing to do with how many elements there are.

Comment: that's not really how the N works in nth-child

Comment: But if 2n refers to evens, then that means every 2 elements right? So 3n would be every three elements right? I'm not getting the logic. How would you modify the formula, thank you.

Comment: which cells do you want to affect, and when?

Comment: I want to modify a column at a time. For the box of cells with class "components". I need to be able to specify the column at the right time as well. Thank you.

Comment: I think that we are having trouble helping you because we understand that you want to affect the `.components` cells and you want to affect one at a time, but that's not very specific. Do you want to affect the first one? The second? The first and third? It may help you to get a better understanding of how `:nth-child()` really works. The 'n' is not the number of elements. It is an integer that starts at zero and increases by one each iteration. Check out this tester to troubleshoot: https://css-tricks.com/examples/nth-child-tester/

Comment: I really have no idea what you're trying to do there. Try to clarify.

Comment: For the cells with "component" they for a grid. In that particular grid I am referring to it's rows and columns. So when I get the data back for column one i want to update column in one go. Then when I get the data back for column 3 I want to update the third column in that grid of "components". it's asynchronous, so I don't know which column I am taking about at a time until the data is returned. For the purpose of this, populating column 1 would explain the logic to me.

Comment: *they form a grid (typo sorry)

Comment: So s1:37, s2:37, s3:37, s4:37, s5:37, s6:37, s7:37 would be column 1

Comment: The green and yellow grid below the blue-ish totals row.

Comment: The cells with red text, but the first row is out of position.

Comment: that nth tester works how I would imagine (the same logic I am using but with a zero index starting point). That must be the problem with the first row.

Comment: "It is an integer that starts at zero and increases by one each iteration." That's the logic I am thinking of "I am imagining the first highlighted cell would be 5: 5(1) + 0 = 5 Then the next highlighted cell index would be 10: 5(2) + 0 = 10" The one and the two in my explanation referred to the iteration

Comment: I have just tried my formula of other standard tables on w3Schools and the logic worked how I expected. I was able to modify each column that I wanted to. I think it's because my table is unusually structured. I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not working as you expected for the first row after "Total" because that row has seven columns in it. `td.components:nth-child(5n+2)` will only apply its styles to the 2nd child (if that child matches `td.components`) and then every 5th child after that 2nd one, providing that every 5th child also matches `td.components`.

However, it will still *count* other children. In your first row, you have the two `rowspan="7"` columns. So it counts those two, doesn't apply the styles to the 2nd column because it does not have a class of `.components`, and then counts 5 columns over, and applies styles to that column, because it *does* have the class `.components`.

In following rows, at least in the *markup*, there are only 6 columns each, so the 2nd column of each row gets the styles applied due to the 2nd column in each of those rows having the class `.components`.

So if you want those first two columns to not be counted you will need to put them in their own row or use some different logic, like integrating a `:not()` selector or something.

Alternatively if you want to use jQuery to apply these styles you can do so, just tell the loop to ignore the first row after the Total row and apply specific styles to that one.

Comment: "Alternatively if you want to use jQuery to apply these styles you can do so, just tell the loop to ignore the first row after the Total row and apply specific styles to that one." I think this solution will be the simplest for me, thank you.